# Better version to prop data from child to parent Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a problem props data from child to parent.
Imagine this. The search input button is the child component and the table is the parent component.
Each type and type I need to pass the information to the parent and further sort array.
Check code:

```
<app-search (sendEvent)="receivedMessage($event)"></app-search>
<table class="w-100">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Name</th>
            <th> Size</th>
            <th> Price</th>
            <th> Date added</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let menu of allMenus | searchInput:searchTerm; let i=index">
            <td> {{ menu.name }}</td>
            <td> {{ menu.size }}cm</td>
            <td> {{ menu.price | currency : 'USD' : 'symbol' : '1.0-0'  }}</td>
            <td> {{ menu.date | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm' }}</td>
            <td> 
                <button class="btn btn-secondary mr-3"> Edit </button>
                <button (click)="removeMenu(menu)" class="btn btn-secondary"> Remove </button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Inside parent ( table ) :

```
searchTerm: any = '';
receivedMessage(searchMessage: string) { 
  if (searchMessage) { this.searchTerm = searchMessage; }
}
```

Inside child component:

```
    <input (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" type="text" placeholder="Search menu items">

  @Output() sendEvent = new EventEmitter;
  searchTerm: any = ''
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onChange(e: string){ 
    this.sendEvent.emit(e);
  }
```

This is work.
But situations in which he does not work:

**When I start deleting everything from the input it sometimes doesn't show me all the data again.**

**When i copy all string inside input**

Second situation is not important more for me.
Only is problem when I delete all typed data from input not clear all results ....

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't enter your `if (searchMessage) { this.searchTerm = searchMessage; }` block because you conditionally check for falsy value - `if (searchMessage)`

When you delete everything from input, the actual value is empty string - `''` which is a falsy value in Javascript.

I would recommend to remove if statement because it can't be anything else than string from your input with `NgModel` applied.

Answer (score 0):

I could not think of any better way of communication to deliver the `searchTerm` from the child component to the parent component.

If you consider another way like using a service, I don't recommend using a service in such a case while it has to be good for communication between multiple threads not only two parent-to-child threads.

Another point to consider:

check the condition in the parent component `if (searchMessage) { }`. This has to be changes to suit your needs because using it like that would not do any thing in case you delete the whole search word `searchTerm = ''` which will not proceed inside your condition.

Add an else statement to this if to suit your both situations.